# block->subject set when using one theme, but not when using identical copy of the theme?

Tags: blocks, theming

I have a theme (based on zen). I made a copy of the theme, replacing all the references to the theme's name in the files. I switched to the new theme and copied all theme settings in drupal (drupal 6).

As far as I can tell everything looks just the same, **except** that on some blocks (notably the footer menu) the name ("Footer Menu") appears. From the theme files i see this is because $block->subject suddenly is set.

What's up with this - if the themes are identical and the configuration is the same, why does one have a block->subject set and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be a known issue. I see [blocks display emptry string for $block->subject](http://drupal.org/node/162899). in this thread someone mentions that they had to modify system.module for this to work. you can check it out in this thread [here](http://drupal.org/node/521668). Looks like a patch is out there for it.

Comment: You were right, this is probably the same issue. Thanks!